# Was there a race to patent the use of Freon as a home refrigerator coolant?

Tags: 20th-century, inventions

[Thomas Midgely, Jr.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Midgley_Jr.)'s hands were in two of the most detrimental scientific breakthroughs of the 20th century: the proliferation of leaded gasoline and the use of [Freon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freon) (a chlorofluorocarbon) as [a household refrigerant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refrigerant).

Recently a colleague suggested that there was another inventor or team working on a household refrigerant alternative at the same time as Midgley and his team, and that both were working to beat the other to patent their solution first.

I have spent a great deal of time researching Midgley and his legacy, and I never saw any mention of a 'race to the patent office.'

Is there any truth to this assertion? At the very least, was there even another team working on a solution?

Comment: It doesn't make much sense: if they were two different methods, as you suggest, then the patent office should have accepted both.

Comment: The 'race' would be to patent a solution FIRST, as it could be more profitable/marketable.

Comment: then it would actually be a race to _ship a product_ first, not to submit a patent. Unless their business plan was to only earn money via royalties, and not to actually sell the finished product.

Comment: Hmm...maybe. I think we're moving away from the heart of the question: was there another team working on a solution? After considering editing the post, I think the current title speaks to the 'was there another team?' end. Edited the post itself to emphasize this.

Comment: Much better now, I'll see if this answer (with its comments) can be converted to a comment then, since it no longer applies but is still relevant.